# Python code for generating Fibonacci numbers is not working

Tags: python, fibonacci

I wrote some code to generate Fibonacci numbers. Here is my code:

```
for i in range (10):
    f=0
    s=1
    t = f + s
    print t
    f = s
    s = t
```

(http://ideone.com/tLEnsi)

I tried to change the value of `f` into `s` and `s` into `t`. It works in C++ but not in python. It gives me 1 ten times in output. How does it works in python?

Comment: That wouldn't work in any language. You re-set the values of f and s in every iteration: you'll never get anything other than 1.

Comment: You initialize f and s inside your loop. How do you expect that to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're resetting the variables at the beginning of the function. Declare them before the loop so they're not reset to 0 and 1 every iteration.

```
f=0
s=1
for i in range (10):
    t = f + s
    print t
    f = s
    s = t
```